# iis 7.5 http to https redirect not working and causing an error

Tags: redirect, https, asp.net

I have a client whom has a site configured in iis7.5 running asp.net 4.0.
The site is configured with a static IP address, with a valid wildcard cert, it has headers setup as wildcard leavemanagement.co.za and www.leavemanagement.co.za.

The clients access the application by using their company name as a sub domain prefix to get their login, etc correctly. I think the app uses the prefix as a form of identification to return the correct info once they login. So for example you goto http://demo.leavemanagement.co.za or https://leavemanagement.co.za to be able to get your login, if you use either of these ways manually the site works 100% fine.

I tried to use various web.config rewrite rules to automate the switch to https automatically, but all it does is cause an application error. as below

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
```

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

- Exception Details:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

- Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

- Stack Trace:

  ```
   [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Leave.Core.Security.FormsAuthenticationUserStateModule.PreSendRequestHeaders(Object sender, EventArgs e) +65
   System.Web.SendResponseExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +137
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
  ```

the rewrite rules i have tried have been numerous, the last one we have tried is this

```
        <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"
                    redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
        <outboundRules>
            <rule name="Add Strict-Transport-Security when HTTPS" enabled="true">
                <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Strict_Transport_Security"
                    pattern=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" value="max-age=31536000" />
            </rule>
        </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
```

If someone can help me please..